# Data parsing in model class from firebase

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I had data in this form in firebase an I need to show facility and its corresponding booking so how I can parse this data in model class.I am new in parsing.
This I have done but I am not able to parse facilityXXXXXXXX in FacilityBooking model class.And then I again I need to parse booking in another booking model class.

```
 struct Facilities_id {

let key: String
var facilities: FacilityBooking
let ref: FIRDatabaseReference


init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    key = snapshot.key
    ref = snapshot.ref
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
}

}
```

This is the code I used for getting data

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "facility")

ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        // 2
        var facility: [Facilities_id] = []

        // 3
        for code in snapshot.children {
            // 4
            let facilityObj = Facilities_id(snapshot: code as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            facility.append(facilityObj)
        }
        // 5
        self.facility_id_Arr = facility
        print("facitlities  ---",self.facility_id_Arr)
    })
```

Comment: you are new in parsing but still you can give a try ..

Comment: I tried but not succeed
struct Facilities_id {
    
    let key: String
    let ref: FIRDatabaseReference
    
    
    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        key = snapshot.key
        ref = snapshot.ref
        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
    }
    
}

Comment: @RahulGupta Show us what you have tried.

Comment: @RahulGupta Also show the code for how you are getting data from Firebase.

Comment: @RahulGupta Don't you getting crash on this line `let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]`? If not can you show the console log for `snapshotValue`.

Comment: No,i am not getting crash and here is the log
Printing description of snapshotValue:
▿ 1 element
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - .0 : "facility1472711955344"
    ▿ .1 : 7 elements
      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - .0 : rateby
        - .1 : Hour
      ▿ 1 : 2 elements
        - .0 : name
        - .1 : Conference Hall
      ▿ 2 : 2 elements
        - .0 : id
        - .1 : facility1472711955344
      ▿ 3 : 2 elements
        - .0 : price
        - .1 : 200
      ▿ 4 : 2 elements
        - .0 : uniqueCode
        - .1 : IRYJKHNV4AU5U
      ▿ 5 : 2 elements

Comment: @RahulGupta Don't print description print directly value of snapshotValue like `print(snapshotValue)`  and add the console log here.

Comment: @NiravD This is the data
["facility1472711955344": {
    desc = "A huge conference hall lol.";
    id = facility1472711955344;
    name = "Conference Hall";
    price = 200;
    rateby = Hour;
    uniqueCode = IRYJKHNV4AU5U;
    url = "http://en.minghui.org/emh/article_images/2011-8-30-minghui-ny-fahui-02.jpg";
}]

Comment: @NiravD are u getting this error "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties" if it is giving then plz comment this line 
var facilities: FacilityBooking

Comment: @RahulGupta Because with init you need to also initialize `facilities` property.

Comment: @RahulGupta Can you show the declaration of `FacilityBooking` struct because with single facility you are having array of bookings.

Comment: I have not made the declaration of facilityBooking its just blank here it is
struct FacilityBooking {
}
Because I don't know to pass the values from Facilities_id to FacilityBooking

Comment: @RahulGupta Then don't you want information of booking like price, starttime,endtime etc..? Also are you able to get other details?

Comment: yes I need to show them on the basis of selected facility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first change your both `struct` like this way.

```
struct Facilities_id {

    let key: String
    let facilityId: String
    var facilities: [FacilityBooking]
    let desc: String
    let name: String
    let ref: FIRDatabaseReference


    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot, id: String, dictionary: [String:Any]) {
        key = snapshot.key
        ref = snapshot.ref
        facilityId = id
        desc = dictionary["desc"] as? String ?? ""
        name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? ""
        let bookingDic = dictionary["booking"] as? [String:Any] ?? [String:Any]()
        facilities = bookingDic.map { FacilityBooking(bookingId: $0, dictionary: $1 as? [String:Any] ?? [:]) }
    }

}

struct FacilityBooking{

    let bookingId: String
    let customer: String
    let price: Int
    let duration: Int
    let uid: String

    init(bookingId: String, dictionary: [String:Any]) {
        bookingId = bookingId
        customer = dictionary["customer"] as! String
        price = dictionary["price"] as! Int
        duration = dictionary["duration"] as! Int
        uid = dictionary["uid"] as! String
    }
}
```

Now simply create the array of `Facilities_id`.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "facility")

ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    var facility: [Facilities_id] = []

    for code in snapshot.children {
        let snapShot = code as! FIRDataSnapshot
        let value = snapShot.value as? [String:Any] ? [:]
        let facilityArray = value.map {  
            Facilities_id(snapshot: snapShot, id: $0, dictionary: $1 as? [String:Any] ?? [:]) 
        }
        facility += facilityArray
    }
    self.facility_id_Arr = facility
    print("facitlities  ---",self.facility_id_Arr)
})
```