# Adding key from parent struct to child struct while parsing issue in swift3

Tags: ios, swift

Here I filtered all the bookings from all facilities which are under selected unique code. So now I have array of bookings of all facilities which have all the fields of booking but now I want to know the selected booking’s facility name ref [Data parsing in model class from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337405/data-parsing-in-model-class-from-firebase/)

```
var booking_arr = NSMutableArray()

func filterBooking() {
    self.booking_arr.removeAllObjects()
    var bookArr:[FacilityBooking] = []
    user_uid = "iBr9DOlpGma5t5apgl4JM9cO7w62"
    for item in self.facility_id_Arr {
        for item2 in item.facilities {
            if (item2.uid == user_uid) {
                bookArr.append(item2)
            }
        }
    }
    self.booking_arr.addObjects(from: bookArr)
}
```

Comment: The problem is you are looping through the `self.facility_id_Arr`'s `facilities` and then appending object in array, to solved the problem there is only one way either add name property in `FacilityBooking` or dictionary which contains key as name and value as array of it.

Comment: I asked the server side to add facility id in each booking and rest i done by using that key.